# Node Express Form registration with file upload not working

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload

I tried to create a registration form with upload a photo in node express using connect-busboy. When I using multi-part/form-data server doesn't read the other text fields in the form. Please any one help me.

my jade file is,

```
form(class='form-signin', action='/s/upload', method='POST', enctype='multipart/form-data')   

                            input(type='text', name='classname', class='form-control', placeholder='Classname',required)
                            input(type='text', name='subject', class='form-control', placeholder='Subject',required)
                            input(type='text', name='chapter', class='form-control', placeholder='Chapter',required)
                            input(type='text', name='module', class='form-control', placeholder='Module',required)
                            input(type='text', name='name', class='form-control', value = user.username,required)
                            input(type='file', name='thumbnail', class='form-control')
                            input(type='text', name='regid', class='form-control',value = "#{user._id}")

                            button(class='btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block', type='submit') Register
                            span.clearfix
                    #message
                        if message
                            h1.text-center.error-message #{message}
```

My registration script is,

```
router.post('/upload', function(req, res, next)

   { 

    console.log("help..........."+req.body.chapter);
    console.log("Got a POST request for the homepage");
    var ar =dirname+'/uploads/'+req.body.thumbnail;
    var person = new Upd({
        classname: req.body.classname,
        subject: req.body.subject,
        chapter: req.body.chapter,
        module: req.body.module,
        name: req.body.name,
        thumbnail: req.body.thumbnail,
        filedtls: ar,
        regid: req.body.regid
        });

    person.save(function (error, data){
       if(error) {throw error; }

        });

    var fstream;
    req.pipe(req.busboy);
    req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
        console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
        console.log("Uploading: " + dirname);

     fstream = fs.createWriteStream(dirname + '/uploads/' + filename);
     file.pipe(fstream);

     fstream.on('close', function () {    
         console.log("Upload Finished of " + filename);  
         console.log("file lo " + ar); 
         res.redirect('/home');           //where to go next
     });
 });
});
```

Comment: Normally it's multipart/form-data not multi-part/form-data. Also it's better if you give us the code you use to do it or we can't help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation say to retrieve fields you have to add :

```
req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
    console.log("Uploading: " + filename);
    console.log("Uploading: " + dirname);
req.busboy.on('field', function(fieldname, val, fieldnameTruncated, valTruncated) {
      console.log('Field [' + fieldname + ']: value: ' + inspect(val));
    });
req.pipe(req.busboy);
```

Comment: i tried it but still have a problem. It shows inspect not defined error.